# Call Jquery function in a separated file from custom wordpress widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i make a custom wordpress widget, in the frontend i have a button that call a function into a script file (js/gecofidelitycustom.js). This function is under a separated file and it use Jquery. My problem is how i call from button this function. It seems that don't see function, but my script at load is correct execute. Thanks in advance

This is my code:

```
`<?php
add_action('widgets_init', 'gecofidelity_register_widget');

function gecofidelity_register_widget() {
    register_widget('GecoFidelity_Widget');
}

add_action('init', 'register_script');

function register_script() {
    //wp_register_script('jquery', "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
    wp_register_script('custom_jquery', plugins_url('js/gecofidelitycustom.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));

    //wp_register_style('new_style', plugins_url('css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gecofidwidget_required_scripts');

function gecofidwidget_required_scripts() {

    // wp_enqueue_script('jsCustom', GECOFIDWIDGET_FOLDER_URL . 'js/jquery.js');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jsCustom', GECOFIDWIDGET_FOLDER_URL . 'js/bootstrap.min.js');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jqueryJS', GECOFIDWIDGET_FOLDER_URL . 'js/gecofidelitycustom.js', array('jquery'),'2.1.1');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');
    //wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapStyle', GECOFIDWIDGET_FOLDER_URL . 'css/bootstrap.min.css');
}



class GecoFidelity_Widget extends WP_Widget {
public function __construct() {
    parent::WP_Widget('GecoFidelity_Widget', 'GecoFidelity Widget', array('description' => 'Grazie a questo widget é possibile visualizzare una lista degli ultimi post e dei più commentati'));
}

public function form($instance) {

    $defaults = array(
        'title' => 'GecoFidelity',
        'operative_mode_ID' => NULL,
        'operative_mode_type' => NULL
    );

    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults);
    $opmodetype = isset($instance['operative_mode_type']) ? $instance['operative_mode_type'] : 'company';
    ?>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
                    <strong>Titolo:</strong>
                </label>
                <input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />

            </p>    

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_ID'); ?>">
                    <strong>Operative Mode ID:</strong>
                </label>
                <input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_ID'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('operative_mode_ID'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['operative_mode_ID']; ?>" />

            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_type'); ?>">
                    <strong>Operative Mode Type:</strong>
                </label>
                <!--input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php //echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_type');  ?>" name="<?php //echo $this->get_field_name('operative_mode_type');  ?>" value="<?php //echo $instance['operative_mode_type'];  ?>" /-->
                <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_type'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('operative_mode_type'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['operative_mode_type']; ?>">
                    <option value="company" <?php echo $opmodetype == 'company' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>company</option>
                    <option value="user" <?php echo $opmodetype == 'user' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>user</option>
                </select>
            </p>


    <?php
}

public function widget($args, $instance) {


    extract($args);

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    echo $before_widget;
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    ?>
    <?php wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery'); ?>
            <div>
                        <p>
                            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('operative_mode_ID'); ?>">
                                <strong>N. Scheda:</strong>
                            </label>
                            <input class="" type="text" id="nscheda" />
                        <p id="msgPunti" class="hidden">Il tuo punteggio è di: </p>
                        </p>

                        <button id="btnControllaPunti"  class="btn btn-default">Controlla</button>
            </div>


    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}

public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);

    $instance['operative_mode_ID'] = strip_tags($new_instance['operative_mode_ID']);

    //$instance['operative_mode_type'] = strip_tags($new_instance['operative_mode_type']);
    $instance['operative_mode_type'] = strip_tags($new_instance['operative_mode_type']);

    return $instance;
}

}

?>
```

**js/gecofidelitycustom.js:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // do_stuff();
    console.log( "Eseguito Jquery 2!" ); //this is execute correctly at load of widget on frontend

    jQuery("#btnControllaPunti").click(function(){
        alert("ciao");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, what function are you trying to call from the button click?

Comment: Also, if you are going to use the version of the DOM ready handler that passes a locally scoped `$` for jQuery... then at least use the `$("#btnControllaPunti")` instead of `jQuery("#btnControllaPunti")` :) A better shortcut version is actually `jQuery(function($){ your code here using $ instead of jQuery });`

Comment: check if the btnControllaPunti button is in your html and then, using debug tool like firebug, watch for jQuery("#btnControllaPunti") object inserting a break point into jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) .... bye

Comment: @gaemaf: `<button id="btnControllaPunti" ` *is* in his example. Whether it actually makes it into the final page is a valid point :)